# When the OnApplicationEnd event fires it can no longer resolve the mappings I have defined in Application.cfc

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am running ColdFusion 9,0,1,274733 with hotfix 2 applied on a Windows 2008 Server 64-bit with IIS.

I have written a cfc to handle logging (user auditing) to a database table. Basically I call this cfc at different points during the request cycle.  On application start, on request end, on application end and when errors occur. It all works perfectly well until the application expires.

So here are some relevant parts from my Application.cfc.
I am defining a mapping to the cfc's location outside of any cffunction like so:

```
this.versionfolder="version1";
this.mappings["/modules"]="C:\Webroot\folder\#this.versionfolder#";
```

Then in the aforementioned application events I can call my logging cfc like so:

```
<cfinvoke component="/modules/LogIt" method="Store" />
```

This works fine until the application expires.  When the code fires my cfinvoke for the logging module in the OnApplicationEnd method I get this error:

```
Message: Could not find the ColdFusion component or interface /modules/LogIt.  
Detail: Ensure that the name is correct and that the component or interface exists.
```

I know that the cfc exists it has been calling it the same exact way throughout the application's life span.  Has anybody else seen this behavior?

To throw a wrench at this, the application that I am having this problem with is located in the web root. I have another application, running on this same server, which is located in a sub-folder of this application (they have different application names).  I am using the exact same logic in that Application.cfc referencing the same logging cfc via that application's mapping and it works fine on application end.  I am stumped and have not been able to find anything online about this specific scenario.

To be clear, my application in the web root fails every time on application end.  My application in the sub-folder works every time.  Not sure if this is relevant but the web root application is started (accessed) before the sub-folder application.  Although I have tested only hitting the web root application and it still fails.  I have also tried using dot-notation for the component name but it still fails.

Comment: The component's name is "LogIt" but CF returns a message about a component named "Log"? Is that correct or is that just a typo on your part?

Comment: Oops, sorry, yes that was a typo on my part.  I have corrected the typo in the error message.

Comment: Has nobody else come across this issue?  Anybody else have any idea what might be going on?  This is not really a show-stopper since I am just trying to log the fact that the application has ended but at this point I'm very curious as to why it is failing in the root and not in the sub-folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just did some research into this because I spotted [another question here asking much the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10949762/onsessionend-has-different-rootpath-then-my-running-application/13213081).

[My findings](http://adamcameroncoldfusion.blogspot.co.uk/2012/11/applicationcfc-set-mappings-dont-work.html) were that there's a but in CF8-10 that result in Application.cfc-set mappings do not work in onApplicationEnd() (nor indeed in onSessionEnd() in CF8).  the work around is to set the mappings in CFAdmin. Not much of a workaround, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks so much for looking into this Adam.  I thought I was the only one having this issue.  I have voted for the bug that you raised at Adobe.  As I mentioned in the bug and your blog I will also post here.  I have two Application.cfc files; one in the webroot and another in a sub-folder of that webroot.  The same code is written in the OnApplicationEnd of each.  The sub-folder code will run fine but the webroot code will fail not being able to resolve the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

onApplicationEnd fires AFTER the application has ended, so the application scope is no longer available. 
Because your sub application is in a subfolder when its onApplicationEnd method fires it still can access its parents application scope.

`Use the ApplicationScope parameter to access the application scope; you cannot reference the scope directly; for example, use Arguments.ApplicationScope.myVariable, not Application.myVariable.` - [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d47.html)

Comment: The ColdFusion mappings (this.mappings) are not part of the application scope.  The part that is failing (in my opinion) is the resolution (dereferencing) of the '/modules' mapping that is being defined in Application.cfc.  The two applications are separate, they do not access each other.